# submitted data through form but not stored in database

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created models.py as well as views.py, wanted to submit data through the front page and those need to store in the database but failed to sent data. when I click to submit after fillup the form it goes to the else block which is mentioned in views.py but not checking if statement. help appricated.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

# creating modeles here and storing in database acts as mysql

class Contact(models.Model):
    usn = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    sem = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Contact


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        usn = request.POST.get('usn','')
        name = request.POST.get('name','')
        sem = request.POST.get('sem','')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone','')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')

        if usn and name and sem and phone and email:
            contact = Contact(usn = usn, name = name, sem = sem, phone = phone, email = email)
            contact.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Enter all details")
    return render (request, 'index.html')
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>formpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        MINI PROJECT
      </div>
    <br>
    <!--THE FORM STARTS HERE AND ITS IMPORTANT -->
    <form method="POST" action="/">
          
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>USN</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usn" name="usn" placeholder="ENTER USN" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="ENTER NAME">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>SEM</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sem" name="sem" placeholder="ENTER SEM">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>PHONE</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="ENTER PHONE">
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
  

        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the email input instead of using the `name` attribute you just have the `id` attribute _twice_ (`id="email" id="email"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if all names are match in your index.html

If all are match, Then:

Print all of the following to see which field is giving you the problem

```
print('1', request.POST[usn])
print('2', request.POST[sem])
....
```

Comment: checked all matches.. can you see the page above i have updated html page called index.html.. please help me